# Copy range of cells to a new location

Tags: excel, vba

I have a range of cells (dynamic number of rows) that I want to copy over starting with A1 cell. The below code isn't working for me as it is not moving the entire range of cell values from current location to A1. Please advise.

```
Range("E:E").Cut Range("A1")
```

Example,

If range in E is 50 rows, the cut and move should start at A1 and end at A50.
If range in E is 999 rows, the cut and move should start at A1 and end at A999.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment above, see below code:

```
Sub CutPaste()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim sRow As Long, eRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'set the last row of data
    eRow = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'find the start row of data
    For i = 1 To eRow
        If ws.Range("E" & i).Value <> "" Then
            sRow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'now cut and paste
    ws.Range("E" & sRow, "E" & eRow).Cut ws.Range("A1").Paste
    'clear clipboard and object
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
Sub Kopy()
    Dim N As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E1:E" & N).Cut Range("A1")
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

You do not need to specify the same dimensions for the destination.  A single cell will do.

Before:

[image]

and after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response but it didn't solve my problem. Reason is, my data starts from cell E10 (and is dynamic in number of rows). In the above method, it copied over everything to A10. I want it to copy over to A1.